# Why does this code works well? It changes the Constant storage area string;

Tags: linux, module, kernel, constants

this is  a simple linux kernel module code to reverse a string which should Oops after insmod,but it works well,why?

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
static char *words = "words";
static int __init words_init(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "debug info\n");
  int  len = strlen(words);
  int  k;
  for ( k = 0; k < len/2; k++ )
  {
     printk("the value of k %d\n",k);
     char  a = words[k];
     words[k]= words[len-1-k];
     words[len-1-k]=a;        
 }
 printk(KERN_INFO "words is %s\n", words);
 return 0;
}
static void __exit words_exit(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "words exit.\n");
}
module_init(words_init);
module_exit(words_exit);
module_param(words, charp, S_IRUGO);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha!,I get the answer from the linux kernel source code by myself;When you use the insmod,it will call the  init_moudle,load_module,strndup_usr then memdup_usr function;the memdup_usr function will use kmalloc_track_caller to alloc memery from slab and then use the copy_from_usr to copy the module paragram into kernel;this  mean the linux kernel module paragram store in heap,not in the  constant storage area!! So we can change it's content!

Answer (score 0):

`static` != `const`.

`static` in your example means "only visible in the current file". See [What does "static" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

`const` just means "the code which can see this declaration isn't supposed to change the variable". But in certain cases, you can still create a non-const pointer to the same address and modify the contents.

[Space removal from a String - In Place C style with Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106752/space-removal-from-a-string-in-place-c-style-with-pointers/9106798#9106798) suggests that writing to the string value shouldn't be possible.

Since `static` is the only difference between your code and that of the question, I looked further and found this: [Global initialized variables declared as "const" go to text segment, while those declared "Static" go to data segment. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954403/global-initialized-variables-declared-as-const-go-to-text-segment-while-those)

Try `static const char *word`, that should do the trick.

Comment: I mean the  words="hello" ,in the expression,  "hello"  store in  the Constant storage area, which we can't change it's content; if you  write the words_init function  in  a normal  c program  with  main,it will get segmentation fault; but  why it works  well in linux kernel  module?

Comment: You want to believe that `"hello"` is in the text segment. Did you check this by looking at the assembler input or by dumping the symbol table of the object file?